# Safari: get URLs of images displayed in Web Inspector

Tags: macos, safari, applescript, google-chrome, javascript

How do I get the list of the resources loaded in Safari's Web Inspector? **(Web Inspector > Resources > Images)**

My goal is to download all images shown in the inspector.

These are the manual steps:

1. open web inspector (CMD + Shift + I; Develop > Show Web Inspector)
2. click the "Resources" tab
3. Navigate to your desired resource (fonts, images, scripts, stylesheets)
4. CMD + double-click the desired resource. This loads your desired image/script/css in a new Safari tab.
5. close web inspector
6. copy resource's URL (CMD + L, CMD + C) and close the tab (CMD + T).
7. repeat for the remaining resources.

I think this should work with JavaScript / AppleScript.

Thanks.

Comment: How would your Applescript know the resource you want the URL for? And, probably more important, once you have the URL what do you want to do with it (details on that might open the door for other approaches to the problem)?

Comment: I imagine that Safari is able to list the URL for each element displayed under 'Resources'. I want to download the images that are visible in the web inspector (see my edit above).

Answer (score 1):

It's a relatively simple task actually.  Using Automator app, Just create a new workflow and add these to following actions...

1. Get current webpage from Safari
2. Get Image URLs from webpage

   [image]

Comment: Any chance you know how to do the same thing but with Video URL's?

Comment: Give me a link other than YouTube or  Facebook  or Similar, Containing embedded video... And I will give it a shot